# Bootstrap 4 - How to re-position some navbar elements for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So using bootstrap 4 I've created a navbar that collapses  into a button when the screen gets too small. When it isn't collapsed, the navbar is setup in the perfect order. However, when it does collapse behind a button, one item (the icon image) is centered while the rest of the items are to the left. How can I make the icon go to the left ONLY when the navbar has collapsed (like the rest of the items).

I've tried doing "float-md-left" on the icon image, however that made no changes.

```
<!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mx-auto">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">The Party<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Current Stadium</a>
                    </li>

                    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto float-sm-left" href="#"><i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i></a>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">RSVP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Stadium History
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2017 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2018 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2019 Stadium</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you point. this is happing due to `mx-auto` class.

Is there any specific reason for applying `mx-auto` class? Otherwise, you can remove itself.

Also, please remove float class.

Please have a look on below code.

```
<a class="navbar-brand mx-lg-auto" href="#"><i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i></a>
```

```html
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->



   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfrOj+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mx-auto">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">The Party<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Current Stadium</a>
                    </li>

                    <a class="navbar-brand mx-lg-auto" href="#"><i class="fas fa-football-ball"></i></a>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">RSVP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Stadium History
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2017 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2018 Stadium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2019 Stadium</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, ill remove those two things. Also, to clarify, the mx-lg-auto will only center it on a large screen (hence the lg)? Still new to bootstrap

Comment: yes, mx-lg-auto will only center it on large screen ( above 1200px). Thanks.